# UIImage imageWithData takes a few moments to appear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, grand-central-dispatch

I have a typical "drill down" style app with a `DetailViewController` that includes a `UIImageView`, `UIWebView`, and a few `UILabel`s. The problem is that `imageView` takes a while longer to load! It is white (the background color) for a few moments, then finally loads after 3-5 seconds (probably the amount of time it takes to download).

The code is:

```
- (void)loadSummary {
    self.dogFood = [[IKFetcher sharedFetcher] fetchDogFoodInfoForId:self.dogFoodId];
    self.dogFoodAnalysisArray = [[IKFetcher sharedFetcher] fetchDogFoodAnalysisArrayForId:self.dogFoodId];
    self.dogFoodRating = [[IKFetcher sharedFetcher] getAvgDogFoodRatingForId:self.dogFoodId];
    if ([self.dogFood.dfImageUrl length] != 0) {
        self.dogFoodImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.dogFood.dfImageUrl]]];
    }
}
```

and the call to `loadSummary` is wrapped in a `dispatch_async` call.

What can I do to make the app wait for the image to download?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're giving `dataWithContentsOfURL` a remote URL. It takes to time to download it, plus it might never arrive. That's risky. Instead, show a placeholder and use `NSURLConnection` to download the real image in the background; it will call the delegate when it's got the image and now you can display it instantly.

Comment: Forgive me, but could you provide code or pseudo-code with what you describe? Should it be a synchronous `NSURLConnection`?

Comment: No, that would defeat the whole purpose. — Apple has good code demonstrating use of NSURLConnection, or grab my background downloader example here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-4-Book-Examples/tree/master/p754p772downloader

Comment: Look at SDWebImage for an easy drop-in for background downloading of images over HTTP.

Comment: @matt the background downloader example you provided was exactly what I was looking for - pretty condensed and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) so you don't need to implement it yourself.